# Spacefield with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

i want to program a 2D-sqare Gamefield. The gamefield shall consits of 9 subfields. **The Gamefield shall be an Image**, like an Spacefield or so. Here you can see the concept, and how it shall later look like (just a mockup :P)

[image: Gamefield]
[image]

Within this field i want to move a Object from one field to the other (vertical /horizontal) . But i don't know how i can realize that. I had think of an multidimensional array, but i don't know if this is the right way to do this. I need to know, at which pixel in the image the new field begins. But i think its no good idea to code that hard. I want to do this with Jquery, CSS and HTML. It shall become a very simple online game.

Qapla'

Comment: You want to move the object using drag and drop? or on click??

Comment: Oh sry, on click, on a button or so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In game development these fields are usually called tiles.

It's perfectly fine to create a multidimensional array of `Tile`s.
Whether they hold their own position or if it's up to a separate renderer is up to your design.

Some links you might be interested in:

- [Tiles and tilemaps overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/Tilemaps) (though this uses a `Canvas`-element)
- [Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) for smoothly moving from one Tile to the next (not as useful when using a `Canvas`)
- [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) if you don't like CSS transitions, you can make use of jQuery as well.

I'd recommend reading up on Tiles in game development first, there are tons of example implementations.